# PHP > Set Default Timezone

Tags: php, timezone

We want to set the timezone up as a variable in PHP to account for different timezones / daylight savings.

Our code works perfectly when hard coded:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Brisbane');
```

But when we add a variable it dies. I am not sure why.

```
$setzone = "Australia/Brisbane";
date_default_timezone_set('".$setzone."');
```

Comment: `date_default_timezone_set($setzone);` > because single quotes are not evaluate variables

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Where is a syntax error? Which is? `date_default_timezone_set(): Timezone ID '&quot;.$setzone.&quot;' is invalid in ...` ?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Script was evaluated correctly. Only value was invalid. Test it yourself. There are no parse error.

Comment: Yes You're right. Comments removed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you will add quote then variable behaving as `string` for instance

```
$setzone = "Australia/Brisbane";
echo '".$setzone."';
```

**Output** :

> ".$string."    //output as string not a variable value

So you need to remove quote when passing string into variable

```
date_default_timezone_set('".$setzone."');
```

to

```
date_default_timezone_set($setzone);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$setzone = "Australia/Brisbane";
date_default_timezone_set("$setzone");
```