# How do I make it so time loads in a specific timezone in PHP?

Tags: php, sql

My question is pretty simple but I'm not sure how to do it.

Currently I have a script that loads time and account and etc and executes it in the database but this is what I'm using.

```
$time = time();
```

The issue here is that it's loading the time from their own computer which can easily be abused since my script only enables you to use it every x hour(s). So what I'd like to do is to set a default timezone that the script will use instead of loading the time from their own computer.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: with a simple search you can achieve these kind of questions! just use php default timezone function. for example: date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25616060/php-set-default-timezone This thread seemed to solve my problem, very useful thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd determine the time in the database. I don't know which DB you're using but in MySQL you can use `NOW()` as a default value and you don't need to worry about it in your script anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date_default_timezone_set` method to set default timezone, see example below:

`date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');`

Comment: Which doesn't solve the problem, that the user executing the script can just change their time, and can use the script again.

Comment: How would this be abused if the time is already set for a timezone? Or is it possible to load from a website instead?